# Etiquette for Updating Answers

Tags: discussion

What's the best way to handle a situation where you post a thorough answer, and then someone else posts an answer that basically says "What he said, but here's another relevant detail."  For example, see [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-can-i-tell-the-day-of-the-week-of-a-date/1193#1193) to a question, which is followed by two useful follow-ups by others which are incomplete on their own.  In terms of a simple, complete reference, it could make sense to edit the main answer and add in the additional info - but then those authors wouldn't get credit/reputation for their contributions.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone just wants to add in a point I suggest adding a comment on the original answer. The comment can be voted up and the original poster can make an edit reflecting the extra information (with proper attribution and link to said comment, of course.)

Example:

> **Edit**: Answer updated to include relevant points made by Person X
>   below

Comment: I agree, when folks leave comments.  But is it appropriate to do the same thing when Person X actually left it as a separate answer, not as a comment?  Or should we encourage them to comment, instead?

Comment: Potentially both. Definitely leave a comment explaining why you think their answer might be more appropriate as a comment on answer X. If the original response has been marked as an answer I might edit it; it gets tricky because you don't want to appear to be stealing content to improve your answer.